# How to check if the condition is true at least once in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, any

Let's say I have several lists. If the number 1 appears at least once, I want to return it as True. If there are no instances of 1 appearing, then it is False. So let's say I have several lists.

```
[2.0,2.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0]
[1.0, 2.0]
[3.0, 1.0]
[3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

The outputs would be:

```
False
True
True
True
True
False
```

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: The code example

```
def is_walkable(i,j,current_board):
    # find all the diagonal neighbours of (i,j) that are on board and put them into a list
    diagonal_neighbors = [(i+1,j-1),(i+1,j+1),(i-1,j-1),(i-1,j+1)]
    # loop over the list of neighbours to see if any of them is empty 
    neighbor_values = []
    for neighbor in diagonal_neighbors:
        row = neighbor[0]
        col = neighbor[1]
    # if there is an empty neighbour, return True, otherwise return False
        if on_board(row,col,current_board):
            neighbor_values.append(current_board[row,col])
        for neighbor in neighbor_values:
            if any(neighbor_values) == 1:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

and the testing code is:

```
current_board = initial_board(empty_board)
print(is_walkable(0,1,current_board) == False)
print(is_walkable(2,1,current_board) == True)
print(is_walkable(2,7,current_board) == True)
print(is_walkable(5,0,current_board) == True)
print(is_walkable(5,6,current_board) == True)
print(is_walkable(6,1,current_board) == False)
```

All outputs should be "True." This is for a game of checkers on an 8x8 board.

Comment: `['1' in a_list for a_list in list_of_lists]`

Comment: You say "all outputs should be `True`", but your code shows you printing `== False` for some and `== True` for others. What exactly are you testing for here - what is the expected result and what is the result you're getting instead?

Comment: The testing code was provided to me. I didn't type it and I know it's not very intuitive, but something similar has worked before. Essentially, if the function's correct output is false and we set it  == false, then the output is true.

Comment: My results come out as False True True True True False, but should come out as True True True True True True. I can send the whole notebook if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
xss = [
    [2.0, 2.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0],
    [1.0, 2.0],
    [3.0, 1.0],
    [3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0],
]

print(any(1.0 in xs for xs in xss))
```

`any` will cause the generator `1.0 in xs for xs in xss` to keep checking lists in `xss` until one contains `1.0` with `1.0 in xs`.

Check the documentation on `any` and generators and comprehensions if you want to fully understand the solution, but I think the solution is clear and easy to understand by itself.

If you just want a list of boolean values for the lists:

```
has_one_xss = [1.0 in xs for xs in xss]

print(has_one_xss)
```

Prints:

```
[False, True, True, True, True, False]
```

Comment: Thank you! However, these lists are not contained in a list. The lists are independent of each other. How do I do this one at a time? So if I'm just looking at [2.0,2.0] by itself, how do I set it to false?

Comment: Please update your question with an actual code example, so I don't have to guess where your lists are and what your variables are called.